# bind1st and bind2nd

Tags: c++, stl

i had a view at the below references:

[bind1st](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/bind1st/)

[bind2nd](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/bind2nd/)

what i did not understand is the difference between the two.
Can anyone help me to get to know the difference.an example would be more helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`bind1st` binds the first argument (e.g. you have `foo(int a, int b)`, then `bind1st(foo, 1)(bar)` will be equivalent to `foo(1, bar)`), `bind2nd` the second one. Don't use them, though, they're nigh useless — use generalised [`boost::bind`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/bind/bind.html) instead (or `std::bind` in C++0x).

Comment: If you don't have C++0x or don't want to bring boost dependency they come quite handy.

Comment: they had a marginal use for unary predicates ... however agreed if you want a functor use `boost::function` in conjunction with `boost::bind`

Comment: @ChristianRau: That's why I said 'almost' not 'completely' useless. Though avoiding Boost is just counter-productive.

Comment: As far as I can tell a large portion of C++0x is adopting boost anyway ... it'll be mostly standard soon :)

Answer (score 3):

Assume you have a function object `f(x,y)` and an algorithm that needs a functoid with just one variable. Then there's two possibilities:

- Set some fixed value for `y` and let the algorithm work on `x`
- Set some fixed value for `x` and let the algorithm work on `y`

That's the difference.

Answer (score 0):

That's obvious. The `bind1st` binds a value to the first operand of a functor (assuming you know what a functor in C++ is), `bind2nd` to the second. But for commutative operators as `+` (or `std::plus`) it actually makes no difference (if you didn't overload `+` with non-commutative behaviour in that example).

Answer (score 0):

bind1st binds the first parameter of a function while bind2nd binds the second parameter. if do operation like plus() functor it will make no difference as addition of two numbers remains same in both the cases, but if u do operation like minus(), then it make difference depending upon u use bind1st or bind2nd,  example 5-4 and 4-5 will generate different results, now u got the difference between bind1st first parameter binding and bind2nd  second parameter binding.